# Force Qihoo 360 Browser to use Chrome Layout Engine

Tags: html, google-chrome, trident

How do you force the Chinese "Qihoo 360 Browser" to use the Chrome Layout Engine instead of the trident layout engine for your website.   Specifically I want all users that use Qihoo 360 Browser that visit my website to use the Chrome38 engine instead of the IE engine.

I have created a site with a valid html5 doctype test but it's still trying to render using trident.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Note: I have got it to work in some cases.  for example if i modify my 
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 taobao.com

and then host my application locally on port 80.  If i visit taobao.com (which redirects to localhost) then it uses Chrome38.  This means that it is using some sort of domainname whitelisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional testing and downloading different versions of Qihoo 360 browser:

You need to make sure that both of these meta headers are set correctly, and make sure it is not cached, as it tends to remember what it was last unless you cache bust it:

trident quirks mode:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
<meta name="renderer" content="ie-comp">`

chrome:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="renderer" content="webkit">`

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings"-"Advanced Settings"-"Browsing engine", and check "Always use Webkit engine".

Comment: To clarify my question I mean from the point of the view of the web-developer developing a website.  How do you make sure that if anyone is using Qihoo 360 that when they visit your website it forces it to use the Chrome38 engine.